# ListView (asp.net 3.5) read user choices

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-controls

I fillin ascx control (in webpart) with a set of questions. Each question has 2 groups with 4 options to answer.
I use a ListView control to display this set.

```
var itemsToShow = from ...
                  select new
                  {
                     MfKey = item[MVListsManager.MF_KEY],
                     Order = item[MVListsManager.MF_ORDER],
                     MotivationFactor = item[MVListsManager.MF_MOTIVATION_FACTOR]
                  };
QuestionaryListView.DataSource = itemsToShow;
QuestionaryListView.DataBind();
//QuestionaryListView.ItemCommand += ...
//QuestionaryListView.ItemUpdated += ...  i tried this events but they don't fire
```

I have template

```
<LayoutTemplate>
    <table width="100%" border="1px" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Motivation factor</th>
        <th>Importance</th>
        <th>Satisfaction</th>
    </tr>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><span><%#Eval("MotivationFactor")%></span></td>
        <td><asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RBLSignificance" CommandName="Significance" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MfKey")%>'>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No answer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Not important</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A little bit</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Important</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Very impoprtant</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
        <td><asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="RBLSatisfaction" CommandName="Satisfaction" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("MfKey")%>'>
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No answer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Bad</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>So-so</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Good</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Very good</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

So it looks like this

```
--------------------------------------------
               | option1  | option1  
1. Question    | option2  | option2  
               | ...      | ...
--------------------------------------------
```

And I don't know (I've tried a lot) how to read user input, after (or during) he filling the questionnaire.